# Sending a message between client-server with ID - Java

Tags: java, client-server, identifier

Given the function below:

```
void sendMessage(String msg)
{
    try{
        out.writeObject(msg);
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("client>" + msg);
    }
    catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

is there anyway to add like an identifier to the string msg so every message would have an unique ID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can to append the unique id with original message and split the combined string where it need.

```
CombinedString =originalString+"splitIdentifierString"+uniqueId;
```

and call **sendMessage(CombinedString)**

In **sendmessage()** you can split the string and take back orginal message and Id.

```
sendMessage(String msg){
        String a[]=msg.split(splitIdentifierString);
        String message=a[0];
        String id=a[1];
        }
```

Also you can use UUID class to generate unique ids.

```
import java.util.UUID;

UUID idOne = UUID.randomUUID();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could concatenate client ip + nanosec